# How to create Accumulo Embedded Index with Rounds strategy?

Tags: accumulo

I am a beginner in Accumulo and using Accumulo 1.7.2.
As an Indexing strategy, I am planning to use Embedded Index with Rounds Strategy (http://accumulosummit.com/program/talks/accumulo-table-designs/ on page 21). For the same, I couldn't find any documents anywhere. I am wondering if any of you could help me here.

Comment: I can't speak for the author, but it seemed to me that the point of that talk was to get people thinking about trade-offs; when people make decisions about indexing, they should think about what they are giving up. The strategy descriptions seemed very vague to me, and I don't think they were intended to describe specific strategies... but just used to describe a set of general characteristics. If you want embedded indexes w/rounds, you're probably going to want to investigate specific indexing strategies like sharded document-partitioning, and inverted indexes, and design based on your data.

Comment: Thanks Christopher for replying to my question. In my current use case, 1) data is to be streamed into Accumulo table, 2) users needs to query on any columns combination, 3) number of concurrent users are modest(around 50), and 4) atomacity is also a priority. Sharded Document Paritioning AKA Embedded Index startegy (mentioned in the talk by Aaron Cordova)  seems to be matching with my requirement. However, I am not sure how to add Rounds strategy to that.

Comment: By "rounds" I think Aaron simply meant multiple-phase lookups, using secondary indexes stored in other tables, in order to narrow the search in the main sharded document table. In other words: query secondary indexes, process result on client side, use result to narrow search in primary table.

Answer (score 0):

My description of that strategy was mostly just to avoid sending a query to all the servers at once by simply querying one portion of the table at a time. Adding rounds to an existing 'embedded index' example might be the easiest place to start.

The Accumulo O'Reilly book includes an example that starts on page 284 in a section called 'Index Partitioned by Document' whose code lives here: https://github.com/accumulobook/examples/tree/master/src/main/java/com/accumulobook/designs/multitermindex

The query portion of that example is in the class *WikipediaQueryMultiterm.java*. It uses a BatchScanner configured with a single empty range to send the query to all tablet servers. To implement the by-rounds query strategy this could be replaced with something that goes from one tablet server to the next, either in a round-robin fashion, or perhaps going to 1, then if not enough results are found, going to the next 2, then 4 and so on, to mimic what Cassandra does.

Since you can't target servers directly with a query and since the table is using some partitioning IDs you could configure your scanners to scan all the key values within the first partition ID, then querying the next partition ID and so on, or perhaps visiting the partitions in random order to avoid congestion.

What some others have mentioned, adding additional indexes to help narrow the search space before sending a query to multiple servers hosting an embedded index, is beyond the scope of what I described and is a strategy that I believe is employed by the recently released DataWave project: https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/datawave

Comment: Also please feel free to fork that example and put whatever you may develop back up on github so other folks can jump in and contribute!

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Cordova for explaining your approach in detail. As I am using Geomesa (which in turn uses Accumulo) and Scala for my use case, I will see if I could implement that approach and, then, accordingly will fork the given example link. Thanks again.